# What is Option<Box<T>> in rust

Tags: rust

I know Box is a smart pointer that is allocated on the heap. so I can transform a primitive stack-allocated array into a 'dynamic' heap-allocated array using the Box.
But in terms of creating a data structure, let's say a tree, why would I need to Box the pointers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unlike pointers in C, `Box<T>` can't be null. It always holds a non-null pointer to `T`. `Option<Box<T>>` represents the concept of a *nullable* pointer to a heap allocated object.

If you were to store a plain `Box<T>` inside a `T` then each object would contain a non-null pointer to another distinct object. Without nullability, and since `Box<T>` is necessarily acyclic, you'd end up with an infinitely large data structure.

Answer (score 2):

If a `struct`, `enum` or `union` were to directly or indirectly contain itself, without using some kind of pointer, the size would have to be infinite, which isn't possible. By using `Option<Box<T>>`, you only allocate more space when you actually need it.

Answer (score 0):

`Box` pointer is used to determine the size of recursive types. For example

```
enum List{
    // Cons refers to List itself
    // since this is a recursive type its size cannot be determined at compile time
    Cons(i32,List),
    Nil,
}
```

Rust cannot figure out how much space it has to store because of recursion. Instead we write this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List{
    // Cons is similar to a linked list
    Cons(i32,Box<List>),
    Nil,
}
```

now compiler knows that List type has only i32 and Box pointer which is fixed size. when we define a list variable using List enum

```
 let list_var=Cons(1,Box::new(Cons(10,Box::new(Cons(100,Box::new(Nil))))));
```

the problem here is everytime we create Cons variant we wrap it with `Box` even when we have to write `Nil`. 'Nil`is something that has no associated value but with wrapping it with`Box` pointer we are still allocating heap space and this is unnecessary. To overcome this we write this

```
enum List{
    // we avoid allocating heap space for Nil
    // Option's None will replace Nil
    Cons(i32, Option<Box<List>>),
    // Nil,  we remove this
}
```

After that, this is how I will initialize `list_var`

```
// instead of Box::new(Nil) I am using None
let list_var=List::Cons(1,Some(Box::new(Cons(10,Some(Box::new(Cons(100,None)))))));
```